# support vector machines and Lagrange multiplier

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

to find hyperplane we must solve the optimization problem with Lagrange multiplier . I have read many tutorial and they all say the support vectors are the only ones that have Lagrange multiplier  different from zero.

I want to understand why or we just suppose that ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on a math site in SE network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the mathematical perspective, hyperplane can be expressed as (in linear case):

```
w = SUM_i^N y_i alpha_i x_i
```

thus, if some of the lagrange multipliers (`alpha_i`) are zero, their corresponding vectors (`x_i`) do not affect hyperplane at all, as multipling by zero makes this vector dissapear from the computation. Similarly in the kernel case

```
<w, x> = SUM_i^N y_i alpha_i K(x_i, x)
```

for 0 lagrange multiplier, kernel value of corresponding vectors does not matter (again - multipling by zero removes this element).

Consequently we **call** these vectors which are used in any sense to express a hyperplaen - **support vectors**, because these are the only one actually **supporting** the hyperplane, all remaining ones - are ignored in the computations.

Comment: Hello lejlot; but there are several hyperplane, they are not optimal but they separate
then we assume that they equal zero

Comment: You seem to confuse something here. Concept of SV is related to any hyperplane expressed as in reproducing Space theorem,  it does not matter if it is optimal or not

Comment: we apply Lagrange multiplier with  x_i and y_i to obtain w = SUM_i^N y_i alpha_i x_i after we assume for support vectors that have a non-zero multiplier. how we  can calculate these multipliers non-zero please ?

Comment: This is completely different question. Ask it in separate one as comments section is too small